# Is it possible to place an app in Google Play Store with translated app name?

Tags: android, internationalization, google-play

We want to place an android app in Google Play Store. Is it possible to change the name of the app depending on language or country?
I know that it is technically possible (by using "string.xml") but somebody told me that it is not possible to give different names to the same app when placing it in Google Play Store.
I searched in the internet already and looked in help pages of Google Store but was not able to find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.
You can give a specific name for every language/country you want on the Play Store independently of the app'real name.

And/or you can set a different name for your app for every languages by using a different strings.xml files.

The two names (the one on the Play Store page and the real app name for the language) can be different.

For example you can have your app on the Play Store:

- US version: 'My beautiful app'
- Germany version 'Whatever in German'

In you app (strings.xml)

- English version: 'My app'
- German version: 'Mein app'

So if you are a German user, the app will be listed as 'Whatever in German' on the Store but appears as 'Mein app' when the app will be installed.

To set the app name on the store, set:

`Store presence → Store listing → Product details → Title` on the Google play Console

Answer (score 5):

Yes, change the `android:label` property of the `application` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` so that it doesn't use a harcoded value (if it does):

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

You can then specify different values for different languages in `strings.xml`, for each language you want:

In `values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="app_name">App name in English</string>
```

In `values-es/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="app_name">App name in Spanish</string>
```